# How to called TouchesMoved for 2 different UIImageView

Tags: ios, uitouch

Hello I have 2 `UIImageViews` in `UIView`.

Once I touch on `UIImageView` `touchesBegan` method gets called. But once I drag on `UIImageView` then `touchesMoved` is called. But at the same time `touchesMoved` for the second `UIImageView` is also called.

Can you please help me how i can get `touchesMoved` event for both the `UIImageViews`?

This is my code

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(iv1.frame,currentPoint)==YES)
        NSLog(@"iv1 Begin");
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(iv2.frame,currentPoint)==YES)
        NSLog(@"iv2 Begin");
}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(iv1.frame,currentPoint)==YES)
        NSLog(@"iv1 Moved NO");
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(iv2.frame,currentPoint)==NO)
        NSLog(@"iv1 Moved YES");
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(iv2.frame,currentPoint)==YES)
        NSLog(@"iv2 Moved NO");
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(iv2.frame,currentPoint)==NO)
        NSLog(@"iv2 Moved NO");
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(iv1.frame,currentPoint)==YES)
        NSLog(@"iv1 End");
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(iv1.frame,currentPoint)==YES)
        NSLog(@"iv2 End");
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do. Do your two image views overlap? You want to be able to drag each one of the separately? Can you give some more context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two outlets linked to two views and this is the code for reacognize the two view inside touch methods:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];
   touchedView = t.view;
   if (t.view == view1) {

    //todo something with view1;

   } else if (t.view == view2) {

      //todo something with view2

   }
}
```